# Два метода в ViewHolder'e

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть сложность в написании двух методов : `onBindViewHolder`, `onCreateViewHolder`.
Не совсем догоняю что там нужно(пытаюсь переделать listview в recyclerview)

Также в ListView был метод getView, где была реализована следующая логика

```
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    var convertView = convertView
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_language_picker, parent, false)
    }
    val item = getItem(position) as String
    val locale = LocaleTools().parseStringLocale(item)
    var text = LocaleTools().getDisplayLanguage(locale)
    if (!locale.getDisplayCountry(locale).isEmpty()) {
        text += (" (" + locale.getDisplayCountry(locale) + ")")
    }
    (convertView!!.findViewById(R.id.itemInfo) as CustomTextView).text = text
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.check).visibility = if (item == selection) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    return convertView
}
```

Если честно не совсем понимаю куда её можно запихнуть в адаптере recyclerView.

Comment: Это методы адаптера, а не `ViewHolder`'а. Вот в [этой книге](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/136792911/)  подробно расписано, зачем они нужны.

Answer (score 3):

В `onCreateViewHolder` вы должны инфлейтнуть разметку айтема и создать из нее `AdapterHolder`. Обратите внимание как и где инициализированы `view`.

В `onBindViewHolder` поступает ваш `AdapterHolder`, созданный в `onCreateViewHolder`. В нем нужно заполнять данными каждый элемент списка.

Вот мой первый адаптер, когда я начинал пробовать `RecyclerView`. Думаю все станет ясно. Если нет - пишите комментарии. Здесь я выгружаю данные из БД. Что-то типа `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.AdapterHolder>
{
Cursor cursor;

public class AdapterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView time, date, text;
    CardView card;

    AdapterHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        time = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_item_time);
        date = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_item_date);
        text = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_text);
        card = (CardView)itemView;
    }
}

NotesAdapter(Cursor cursor)
{
    this.cursor = cursor;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
{
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public AdapterHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int p2)
{
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.note_item, viewGroup, false);
    AdapterHolder pvh = new AdapterHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterHolder holder, final int position)
{
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    final Long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
    String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.NOTES_DATE));
    String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.NOTES_TIME));
    final String color = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.NOTES_COLOR));
    final String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.NOTES_TEXT));

    holder.time.setText(time);
    holder.date.setText(date);
    holder.text.setText(text);
holder.card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return cursor.getCount();
}
}
```

Для удобства делают метод `bind(int position)` в холдере и вызывают его в `onBindViewHolder`

```
holder.bind(position);
```

А внутри метода `bind` пишут логику биндинга данных. Это, действительно, эффективно.

```
People people = peoples.get(position);
textview_name.setText(people.name);
//etc..
```

Для установки слушателя типа `onItemClickListener` как в `ListView`:

1) Корневому элементу разметки (в котором находится все остальное пишем

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true" <!-- не знаю зачем -->
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" <!-- опционально -->
```

2) В конструкторе холдера ставим

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

3) Сам холдер наследуем от интерфейса

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener
```

4) Реализуем внутри холдера метод `onClick(View v)`

5) Создайте в адаптере переменную слушателя

```
private OnItemClickListener listener;
```

6) Создайте в адаптере интерфейс

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View v);
    //можно сразу передавать модель
    //void onItemClick(People p);
    //или позицию
    //void onItemClick(int position);
}
```

7) Создайте метод в адаптере

```
public void setOnItemClickListener (OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

8) В методе `onClick` (см. шаг 4) пишем

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.root_item_view:
            listener.onItemClick(v);
            //или модель
            //listener.onItemClick(peoples.get(getAdapterPosition()));
            //или позицию
            //listener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
            break;
        case ...
        case ...
    }
}
```

Теперь, в активности/фрагменте можно писать так

```
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(...);
rv.setLayoutManager(new Linear/*Grid/Staggered*/LayoutManager());
RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(datalist);
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View v) {
        //ваша логика
    }
});
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Спасибо в целом пример понятен, но обновил вопрос, дабы разобраться полностью

Comment: @Flippy То есть мое предположение, что логика ViewBinder'a из SimpleCursorAdapter переносится в onBindViewHolder было верным?

Comment: Да. В конструктор холдера приходит `View` итема, в нем нужно искать по id все `View`. В `RecyclerView` паттерн `ViewBinder` уже из коробки

Comment: Добавил немного информации

Comment: @Flippy Спасибо все отлично работает. Только еще момент хотелось бы уточнить нужно ли с RecyclerView использовать CursorLoader или же тут уже это реализовано за кадром (для асинхронного получения данных из БД )?

Comment: @Leo240, ой, я не пробовал :) вроде надо бы, но я с проблемами не сталкивался :D